# .net6 use AddOpenIdConnect with localhost but different with production domain

Tags: .net, nginx, proxy, openid-connect

I use OIDC to authorize user's identity. The oidc provider is PingOne.

```
 service..AddCookie("cookie", options =>
                {
                    // configure diff site cookie
                    // example : AspNetCoreCookie_cookie from authority
                    // options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                    options.Events.OnSigningOut = async e =>
                    {
                        await e.HttpContext.RevokeUserRefreshTokenAsync();
                    };
                }).AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", opt =>
                {
                    opt.Authority = pingOneOptions.Authority;
                    opt.ClientId = pingOneOptions.ClientId;
                    opt.ClientSecret = pingOneOptions.ClientSecret;
                    opt.CallbackPath = new PathString(pingOneOptions.CallbackPath);
                    opt.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                    opt.UsePkce = true;
                    opt.SaveTokens = true;
                    opt.Scope.Add("profile");
                    opt.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("firstname", "firstname");
                    opt.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("lastname", "lastname");
                    opt.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                    };
                    
                    opt.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                    {
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
                        {
                            context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress =
                                GetAbsoluteUri(pingOneOptions.SignOutRedirectUrl,
                                    pingOneOptions.Authority);
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider =  n =>
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "http://production.com/callback";
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
```

Everything goes fine with localhost, cause the redirect url is localhost:8090.
but when I deployed on a VM with nginx proxy pass to localhost:8090.
so I configure the AddOpenIdConnect()

```
   OnRedirectToIdentityProvider =  n =>
   {
      n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "http://production.com/callback";
      return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
```

And When I Complete the Authorize. It's throws an exception

- Exception: Correlation failed.
  Unknown location

I Know that is the cookie problem. because localhost and production domain are not same site. Maybe they can't share the Cookie?

- And I can't set RedirectUrls in oidc's provider.
- Here's my nginx config:

```
server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  production.com;
      
      location / {
           #proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
           #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
           #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
      }
    }
```

Is there any solution to complete the authorize process?